# How can we make the Oauth2 user profile detailed and customized at resource server?

Tags: oauth-2.0

I want to make sense of the Oauth2 flow in my mind. There is a point where I am stuck. Let me summarize what I understand about Oauth2 and please correct me if I am wrong;

- If the user is in the oauth2 client, he enters his account, if not, he registers and returns to the frontend screens. Then a request is sent to the resource server with the tokens received.

If there is no problem so far, there are certain fields in the oauth2 screens to register, but I want the user to have a custom profile. The oauth2 framework does not contain such fields. If the user has successfully completed the flow on the oauth2 register screen, how should I create his profile on my resource server?

My goal here is this,

- any user can see another user's public profile details.
- When the user adds content, the createBy field should be mapped to this profile.
- When the added content is queried, for example /content/123, the response will return the information and profile url of the person who added it.

I don't know how such a process should be handled, can you guide me?